# New(?) flag of Baikonur

Tags: russia, space-art, baikonur-cosmodrome

While watching a [video of deployment of Soyuz spacecraft](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJIArEFIvl8), I noticed a flag next to the launchpad, with sign 'Baikonur' and a graphic of Earth and several stars; one I didn't see anywhere else:

[image]
[image]

Every search for 'Baikonur flag', in English and Russian, return either the standard:
[image],

the flag of Kazakhstan:

[image]

Baikonur badge/logo,

[image]

or assortment of commemorative badges and independent designs by people without any association with Baikonur or Roscosmos. I managed to locate what seems like a very old print of an old variant of the design (with a simple globe of meridians and parallels instead of a picture of Earth) on the flag on a [Flags of the world](http://www.signa-fahnen.de/fotw/flags/kz-reg.html) site:

[image]

and [a photo](http://www.vexillographia.ru/kazakhst/subjects/towns/baikonur.htm) of a flag with this version:

[image]

...but nothing closely resembling the one from the video.

When was that version introduced, what is its relation to all the others, status (an official symbol or just a decorative variant?), and does anyone have a better image of it?

Comment: Further search seems to indicate the "cradling hands" flag is the flag of the town of Baikonur, while the "globe and stars" is the flag of the cosmodrome itself.